# MS Access between dates Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query which retrieves records from a Table within specified date range and inserts them into a new Table (VWDRSSTA).

Although this specific search between the dates is not working as I expected. I am using **Where (Field) Between(Start) And (End)** expression but there is a problem as it does not give out any records from the end date.

Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO VWDRSSTA ( SYSTEM, EREIGNIS, DATUM_ZEIT, ANTRAGSNUMMER, 
VORGANGSNUMMER, VERS_NR_INT, DUNKEL, DOK_ART )
SELECT VWD.SYSTEM, VWD.EREIGNIS, VWD.DATUM_ZEIT, VWD.ANTRAGSNUMMER, 
VWD.VORGANGSNUMMER, VWD.VERS_NR_INT, IIf(VWD.EREIGNIS="POL_AN" And 
VWD.DUNKEL=1,1,0) AS DUNKEL, IIf(VWD.EREIGNIS="EIN-ES" And 
VWD.DOK_ART="EN","EN","") AS DOK_ART
FROM VWD
WHERE ([VWD.DATUM_ZEIT]) Between [Forms]![overview]![start] And [Forms]!
[overview]![end];
```

I have tried using

```
WHERE ([VWD.DATUM_ZEIT]) >= [Forms]![overview]![start] <= [Forms]!
[overview]![end];
```

but it gives me an overflow error. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the data type of your parameters:

```
PARAMETERS 
    [Forms]![overview]![start] DateTime,
    [Forms]![overview]![end] DateTime;
INSERT INTO VWDRSSTA 
    ( SYSTEM, 
    EREIGNIS, 
    DATUM_ZEIT, 
    ANTRAGSNUMMER, 
    VORGANGSNUMMER, 
    VERS_NR_INT, 
    DUNKEL, 
    DOK_ART )
SELECT 
    VWD.SYSTEM, 
    VWD.EREIGNIS, 
    VWD.DATUM_ZEIT, 
    VWD.ANTRAGSNUMMER,  
    VWD.VORGANGSNUMMER, 
    VWD.VERS_NR_INT, 
    IIf(VWD.EREIGNIS="POL_AN" And VWD.DUNKEL=1,1,0) AS DUNKEL, 
    IIf(VWD.EREIGNIS="EIN-ES" And VWD.DOK_ART="EN","EN",Null) AS DOK_ART
FROM 
    VWD
WHERE
    ([VWD.DATUM_ZEIT]) Between 
        [Forms]![overview]![start] And 
        [Forms]![overview]![end];
```

To ignore a time part:

```
WHERE
    [VWD.DATUM_ZEIT] >= [Forms]![overview]![start] And 
    [VWD.DATUM_ZEIT] < DateAdd, "d", 1, [Forms]![overview]![end]);
```

Comment: Still the same! I don't get the records from the 'end' Date.

Comment: That's not the same as an overflow error. It isn't even an error.

Comment: If the end dated records are missing, you have a time part in `[VWD.DATUM_ZEIT]`. So either remove this and adjust your code save future records using `Date()` and not `Now()`. Or adjust your SQL (see edit).